# Visual Studio Crashes on Publish

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, crash, clickonce, publish

I recently installed VS2010 on my new computer. I got all my VS projects copied. The problem is that I can't publish from "project properties \ publish" window by clicking "Publish Now" any more. Visual Studio just crashes and restarts itself. The crash occurs on FTP logon window.

EDIT: Problem solved. It was Visual Studio Achievements extension that was causing the crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. It was Visual Studio Achievements extension that was causing the crash.

Comment: Had the same problem and this solution worked for me too. How could this be?

Comment: I guess just a bug of the extension.

Comment: I think removed it under Tools -> Extensions